# Prevent htmlspecialchars on variables in TYPO3 Fluid template

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-10.x

In a command controller I am using a `StandaloneView` to create a plain text file. The (simplified) code I use for that is:

```php
$view = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(StandaloneView::class);
$view->setFormat('txt');
$view->setTemplatePathAndFilename('EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Templates/test.txt');
$view->assignMultiple([
    'test' => 'test&test',
]);
$content = $view->render();
```

The resulting content if the template is just `{test}` is `test&amp;test`, which I'd expect for html format, but not for txt. I've tried setting the format to `txt`, `text` and `text/plain`, but that doesn't affect the result. I know I can use `<f:format.raw>`, but is there a different way to prevent the HTML characters to be escaped if the format is not `html`?

I'm using TYPO3 10.4.20.

Comment: you can try `fwrite($handle, html_entity_decode($content));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable output escaping with:

```
<!-- Disabling HTML escaping for an entire file -->
{escaping off}

Any variables you render will not need to use f:format.raw
even if they contain special HTML entities. Useful when
you render formats other than HTML; or when you completely
trust (read: escaped before assigning to view) all your
variables that get output.

Use with care - caveat emptor!
```

( https://werkraum.net/devblog/fluid-tipp-8-html-escaping-deaktivieren/ )